# How can a host register its hostname?

Tags: networking, ip, hostname

When I connect a device to my router, or if I use a tool like Advanced IP Scanner to look for devices on my network, the found devices are typically listed with and IP and a hostname. My computer running Windows 7 shows up with the name that can be found by typing `hostname` into cmd.

Some devices, like an embedded device I'm working on, are listed as "unknown" or the IP is simply repeated in the Name column. I can manually edit the etc/hosts file to assign a name for the specific IP of my device and it will show up in the IP Scan results.

My question is, how are these names found by the router/Advanced IP Scanner? What exactly do I need to implement on my device so that it automatically registers a hostname? I already have NetBIOS working, but this does not seem to be related to the hostname.

My embedded device is running the lwIP embedded TCP/IP stack.

Comment: Should probably be migrated to https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like Avahi/Zeroconf but from an ESP-like device(probably).
See this answer:
[Does lwIP support Zeroconf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375681/does-lwip-support-zeroconf)